# Spring 4 Encryptors vs cryptojs

Tags: java, javascript, spring, encryption, cryptojs

I am processing encryption using Spring 4 Encryptors class this way:

```
String salt = KeyGenerators.string().generateKey();
TextEncryptor textEncryptor = Encryptors.text("MY_SECRET_KEY", salt);
textEncryptor.encrypt(json);
```

In the client javascript I am trying to decrypt using CryptoJS

```
var uncrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(serverEncrypted, "MY_SECRET_KEY");
$("#encrypted-data").val(uncrypted);
```

I am guessing I need to revert the Hex encoding part, but I don't understand what needs to be done.

I tried parsing before decrypting, but nothing good out of it.

```
CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(serverEncrypted)
```

The spring documentation says the text method will encrypt in the hex value in the "standard" encryption method and which is 256-bit AES using PKCS #5's PBKDF2

**[Search progress]**

This is how Spring creates its key:

```
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1024, 256);
SecretKey secretKey = newSecretKey("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1", keySpec);
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
```

And the crypting:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
```

iv is a 8 bytes secured random array and is prepended to the encrypted data.

Comment: note that all JS strings are unicode...

Comment: So what does this means?

Comment: it means that the result of encrypting a non-unicode string will differ from the result of encoding the same string in a non-unicode format. i've noticed this is a big compat issue when using a non-js backend and a js front end. maybe your java string is already Unicode in which case i've wasted your gray matter...

Comment: Should I use a different encoding method?

Comment: you need to play around with several until you find one that produces the same output on each end. i found a match for php+js once for AES, but i havn't looked for java. i'm sure something out there can do it, and if you can force unicode or convert to an array of char codes, the one you have might work.

Comment: [That documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/crypto.html) is entirely unhelpful in this case. If you can answer the following questions, then it's easy to implement it in CryptoJS: 1. How many iterations are used for deriving the key with PBKDF2 using the provided password and salt? 2. The documentation says that an additional random IV is generated. Where does it go? Is it prepended/appended to the ciphertext or do you need to query for it somehow? 3. What's the mode of operation? I suspect it's CBC, because of the IV.

Comment: So I guess I should not use the Spring implementation?

Comment: @P.Lalonde I don't see a reason why you should. Java provides a PBKDF2 implementation and an AES implementation (`Cipher`). You can even use PBE which combines the two.

Comment: I've updated my description, based on my research, I should be able to use Spring as my encrypting engine everything is UTF-8 and it seems its doing all the "suggested" stuff I find on Google. I just need to figure out how to revert the process with CryptoJS

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I find out a solution, how to combine Spring 4 Encryptors and CryptoJS.
Spring use in its Encryptors 256-bit AES using PKCS #5's PBKDF2 as provided in the documentation - [Spring Crypto docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/crypto.html#spring-security-crypto-encryption) with IV size equals 16 bytes. That info is crucial when creating code in CryptoJS. Another thing to remember is to use the same salt and iv during whole process of encryption/decryption **one message**. Armed with this info we can start coding (in this example I encrypt message in CryptoJS and decrypt in Spring):
*CryptoJS*

```
const keySize = 256;
const ivSize = 128;
const iterations = 1024;

function encrypt(msg, pass) {
    const salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128 / 8);

    const key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
        keySize: keySize / 32,
        iterations: iterations
    });

    const iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(ivSize / 8);

    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(msg, key, {
        iv: iv,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

    });

    // salt, iv will be hex 32 in length
    // append them to the ciphertext for use  in decryption
    return salt.toString() + iv.toString() + encrypted.ciphertext.toString();
}
```

As you can see result of all encryption is concatenation of *salt* + *iv* + *encryptedMessage*. What is also important that in Spring code I found that key is created with 256 length and in 1024 iterations:

```
PBEKeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), Hex.decode(salt), 1024, 256);
```

Now this prepared result we can take to our Spring code and decrypt:

```
private static String decrypt(String encryptedData, String keyStr) {
        final String salt = encryptedData.substring(0, 32);
        final String encryptedPart = encryptedData.substring(32);
        final TextEncryptor textEncryptor = Encryptors.text(keyStr, salt);
        return textEncryptor.decrypt(encryptedPart);
}
```

Spring AES encryptor will cut part with IV and use it for decryption process by itself. Of course everything will has to be *Hex encoded*, but that's how Spring TextEncrytpors works.

The reverse procedure (encrypt in Spring and decrypt in CryptoJS) will be pretty much the same. In CryptoJS we have to extract *salt* and *iv*:

```
const keySize = 256;

function decrypt (encryptedMessage, pass) {
  var salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedMessage.substr(0, 32));
  var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedMessage.substr(32, 32))
  var encrypted = encryptedMessage.substring(64);

  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
      keySize: keySize / 32,
      iterations: iterations
    });

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, { 
    iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC

  })
  return decrypted;
}
```

I hope it will help somebody :)

Cheers!

Comment: seems like decrypt(js) is not working,
```decrypt(encrypt("hello world" , "1234"), "1234");
```
returns `t.init {words: Array(8), sigBytes: -22}` with toString() = ''